# Chrome devtools enable cache

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I see a lot of questions about how to disable the browser cache in Google Chrome in order to see the changes on the server, but I have the opposite problem. It seems my browser is doing a hard reload every time I press f5. I want to see how the page looks with my javascript edits. How can I do that?

Comment: How did you determine that your browser is doing a hard reload every time? Also, eliminating a hard reload without any extra efforts on your part (i.e. providing certain HTTP response headers for your resource) will possibly result in it getting stuck in your cache.

Comment: I modified a javascript file in the sources tab and pressed f5, and then the javascript reverted back to the the way it was before my edit. I guess that I misunderstand the way that chrome devtools work.

Comment: You need to save your changes with Ctrl+S

Comment: I've tried overwriting the cache file with "save as..." but I'm not sure exactly of the location. In any case, I lose my local edits when I press f5.

Comment: Is the file stored on the remote server not localhost? Then you are out of luck, but the https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-autosave/mlejngncgiocofkcbnnpaieapabmanfl extension is reported to work with WebDAV.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing only `F5` does not do a hard reload in Chrome. When you press `F5`, the local changes that you've made in CSS or JavaScript will be lost. They don't get stored in the cache. However, you should be able to see your JavaScript changes in devtools take effect if that JavaScript part has not yet been called (like document load event).